# How to ignore 'Broken or missing avi index' in VLC via parameter?

Tags: c#, indexing, stream, vlc, avi

I download an avi/video file with wget and want the VLC to play this file. Both actions are called from my C# code:

```
var startWGet = new ProcessStartInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/data/start.bat")
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        var startVLC = new ProcessStartInfo(vlc_path, "--quiet --qt-minimal-view /data/tmp.ts") { };

        Process.Start(startWGet);
        Process.Start(startVLC);
```

But since the video file is not complete during the streaming process, VLC throw an exception form: "Broken or missing AVI index" with options: "Build index then play", "Play as is" and "Do not play". I want the VLC generally to go with "Play as is".

I read something about telling the vlc to do as described in the settings, but that's not what i need, since i program a tool.